# What's wrong with this water ripples code

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to use this [plugin](https://github.com/andyvr/water-ripple) but the call function is not working and not sure what could be wrong. The top code does not produce error but I get a blank white screen after I added (and save) the bottom code to my function.php file. I will appreciate if anyone can help me identify the problem in the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
 //* Enqueue scripts and styles from local files

function genesis_water_ripples() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'ripple', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/ripple.js', array('jQuery')
        );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'genesis_water_ripples');


//* Water Ripples Function    
    JQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.site-title a').waterripple();
});
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the console for any errors? When you use the jQuery variable the "j" needs to be lowercase

Comment: Yes, it says "internal error." The "J" is just an autocorrect error. I had it as "j" in my code.  Thanks for taking look.

Comment: Check your PHP error logs.

Comment: How do I check from local host?